# Website hanging on loading, server side or code?

Tags: javascript, performance, loading

http://www.emmafaull.co.uk/dus/

I run pingdom and it often shows a long wait time for the main page. When I try and access the page there does seem to be a few second hang before it loads and am wondering what causes this as don't have much experience with optimization (or web design for that matter). To me it seems to be either the js cluttering things up or the shared server isn't responding that quickly.

At any rate any help would be appreciated, I've tried the normal avenues to try and sort this out but my experience is showing. If you need any more info just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Pingdom tells me that 60% of the loading time, the browser waits for the server to respond. Another 30% of the time is accounted for establishing the connection. These very high values (combined 90% Not receiving/sending data!), indicate that you should indeed do something about your hardware. ;)

Comment: Ah yes I think I understand pingdom a bit better now (the blue and yellow correspond to waiting for the server to do something, correct?). Thanks for the help and happy christmas.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides of optimization: server (back end) and browser (front end). For most sites, focusing on the front end gives the most bang for the buck. It looks like you are using a shared host which is has a cache that lasts a short while, then takes a long time for the first visitor to visit again. The first time I looked at it, it took about 5 seconds for the server to warm up, then each hit after that is much quicker. I have run your site through a testing tool called websitetest.com. This is very similar to another tool at webpagetest.org, but websitetest is a bit easier to work with.

Take a look at http://www.websitetest.com/ui/tests/50de0ef1bdf73034e4000036/samples/50de0f040fdd7f7964002d71

Now scroll down to the waterfall chart (thats whats taking up most of the page). that first line is basically showing your server processing time. Its taking about 600 ms for the server to serve up the initial HTML. The rest of the time is spent mostly on the front end. You have quite a few css files and those can probably be concatenated together. Each request takes time and serving up the CSS in fewer files will help. Next, I see that all the javascript is loading up before any of the content. I would experiment with moving some of the javascript to the end, as well as concatenating the files where appropriate.

Several of the png files could probably be tweaked a bit using CSS Sprites. Check out the best practices shown at http://yslow.org/ for details on how to optimize the front end. This of course does take some time to do but there are services, such as the one from the company I work for, that automate the process.